# Separating a single linebreak-separated value into multiple values in MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table that puts multiple values into a single value in MySQL, separated by linebreaks. Like this:

```
+------------+-------------+
|    Company | Products    |
|  (VARCHAR) | (TEXT)      |
+------------+-------------+
|  Acme Corp | Medicine    |
|            | Food        |
|            | Phones      |
+------------+-------------+
|  Ajax Corp | TVs         |
|            | Phones      |
|            | Pianos      |
+------------+-------------+
```

I can't do anything about the table structure. Now I need a query that will return this table:

```
+==========+
| Products |
+==========+
| Food     |
+----------+
| Medicine |
+----------+
| Phones   |
+----------+
| Pianos   |
+----------+
| TVs      |
+----------+
```

I prefer a pure MySQL approach, but a solution with PHP is also OK for me.

Comment: beautiful presentation.

Comment: Whats is the maximum nomber of products per row?3?

Comment: @Mihai: No defined max. The rows can have as many as possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no handy ways to split a field with MySQL. (Check the comments in the [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/string-functions.html)). So, the best method seems to obtain all the product records with a simple:

```
SELECT Products FROM YourTable
```

And after in you php code:

```
$products = array_merge($products, explode("\n", $record));
```

for each record.

Answer (score 1):

This will work for 3 products maximum,for more it needs a bit of tinkering

```
CREATE TABLE t 
    (

     company varchar(20), 
     products text
    );
INSERT INTO t
VALUES
('Acme', 'Medicine,Food,Phones'),
('ajax', 'TVs,Phones,Pianos');  



SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(Products,',',1)  FROM t
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Products,','),',',2),',',-1) FROM t
UNION
SELECT SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Products,','),',',3),',',-1) FROM t
WHERE SUBSTRING_INDEX(Products,',',1)<>''
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Products,','),',',2),',',-1) <>''
AND SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(CONCAT(Products,','),',',3),',',-1)<>''
```

Results

```
Medicine
TVs
Food
Phones
Pianos
```